# Sticky footer under floated content

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I have a page where the content is floated in the center so that in any browser size, the content div will always be smack bang in the middle.

Now, I've gone ahead and added a sticky footer to the page, however when the browser window is smaller than expected, the footer displays in front of the floated content.

I am not exactly up to speed with how clearing floats works or exactly how absolute positioning affects relative positioning. I am aware that once I make the footer absolute, it becomes independent of all the other divs, which is naturally not what I want, but this is where I am getting stuck.

My question is, how can I make the sticky footer display at the bottom of the page, but stay under (by under I mean below) the floated content if the height of the browser screen is smaller.

**Here is an example of my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/ySru9/1/**

I have taken the sticky footer code from here: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/style.css and here http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css

I’m sorry if this is a repeat of another question on SO, but I have trawled through and couldn’t exactly find anything the same. I assume that there is some yucky jquery stuff that I need to delve into?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to achieve. There is no "relative float" and if you move the footer-element inside the wrapper, it should be easy to have it appear below the yellow box.

Comment: @feeela sorry, kinda new to this. If I were to move the footer inside the wrapper element, then it would it still not appear below the content but rather display in front of the yellow content? it would seem to be going against what the two sticky-footer websites were trying to make me to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the footer positioned absolute in your body, but make sure the body has some minimal height greater than your yellow container, this could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/PZHvH/

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
#container 
{
  margin: 0 0 0 -100px;
  position: relative;    
}​
```

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ySru9/39/

Comment: Ahh sorry I should clarify, by "under" I meant stop when it reaches the content. Not so that it displays "behind" the content :)

Comment: Close, but it doesn't exactly answer the question :) Could have worked if I added space to the end of my container, but I didn't really want to do that

Comment: you can add space using `margin` property of css. Anyways am glad you got the ans.